# Given a predicate, count number of objects for each subject?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, linked-data

I'm trying to write a SPARQL query that will return a subject and the number of objects it has for a particular predicate.  Here's what I have, but it is not working.

```sql
SELECT ?quote (COUNT(?quotedBy) AS ?no) WHERE {
  ?quote <http://scta.info/property/quotationType> <http://scta.info/resource/quoteType/Biblical> . 
  ?quote <http://scta.info/property/quotedBy> ?quotedBy .
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query isn't legal.  If you check at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), you'll get the response:

> Syntax error:
>
> > Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?quote

You need to **group by** one or more variables.  In this case, you want to count the number of **?quotedBy** values *per* value of **?quote**, so 
 you'd need to **group by ?quote**:

```sql
select ?quote (count(?quotedBy) AS ?no) where {
  ?quote <http://scta.info/property/quotationType> <http://scta.info/resource/quoteType/Biblical> . 
  ?quote <http://scta.info/property/quotedBy> ?quotedBy .
} 
group by ?quote
```